# Difference between "go" and "go down" or "grill" and "grill down"

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I found a phrasal verb while I was reading my book but I didn't know its meaning.

> Well , I am **going down** to the park with some friends.
>   We are going to **grill** some steaks **down** there.

Why doesn't it say *I am going to the park with some friends*? What is the difference between *going* and *going down* or *grill* and *grill down*?

Comment: There is no "grill down", they're saying that the place they're grilling is a downwards directly from where they are.

Comment: ... or it could be a metaphorical directional / locative usage (southwards / located to the south, say).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving "down" almost always means moving to a lower place, either literally or figuratively, but there are several usages where the meaning is "away" from the speaker's current location, no matter its elevation relative to his destination.  We have "down the line" (either literally a rail line or figuratively the course of the future), "down the block," "down wind" (with the wind, away from its "source, which gives us "Down East," the locations on the coast of the state of Maine in the US), and downtown (i.e., the part of the city away from the suburbs).  In Britain, I'm told, it's the opposite, with "down" trains being the ones that leave from a city center.

So "going down to the park" just means going away to the park.

Comment: The [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/down) definition for this sense is good here: **down** adv 2.b.  Away from a place considered central or a center of activity, such as a city or town [or here, probably _home_]: _down on the farm_ ; _sent down to work at the firm's regional office_.

Answer (score 0):

Even if a street or a road is horizontal you can hear people say they go down or up the road. Only local people know whether down or up is the proper adverb to use. They know how the land lies, often these adverbs are in accord with the flow of a river. But other factors may play a role.

So it is of no importance when someone says he is going to the park or down/up to the park.